# Ansible. Module copy with remote_src: yes

Tags: ansible

Tell me please why this command

```
ansible -i hosts/hosts.ini some_group -m copy -a "src=/var/tmp/src/file dest=/var/tmp/dst/ remote_src=yes" -C -D
```

creates directory `/var/tmp/dst/` if i use key --check?

Version ansible [core 2.11.4]

Comment: According [copy.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/copy.py) the module has at least "_Special handling for recursive copy - create intermediate dirs_" via `if not os.path.exists(b_dirname) ... os.makedirs(b_dirname)`. The other occurrence `if not module.check_mode and not os.path.exists(b_dest) ... os.makedirs(b_dest)` seems to has a check.

Comment: that is, in any case, when using the argument remote_src=yes, directories will be created regardless of the key --check ?

Comment: It seems so since in [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameters)_module documentation are also some hints like "_If `dest` is a non-existent path and if either `dest` ends with "/" or `src` is a directory, `dest` is created._" and "_`remote_src` supports recursive copying_"